# Mapstruct ambiguous mapping methods - Spring 2.5.x

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct, spring-repositories

in version 2.5.x of Spring-Boot a method of the JPARepository has been deprecated in favor of another one [(see here, section "Spring Data JPA")](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#spring-data-jpa=)

```
Deprecated: MyObject getOne(Id id);
New one:    MyObject getById(Id id);
```

Mapstruct (1.4.2.Final) now throws the error of `Ambiguous mapping method` because it cannot differentiate which one to use because the signature is identical on both.

I used the `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {MyObjectRepository.class, ...}`
which in turn used to use the `getOne(Id id)` method while generating the implementation of the Mapper. But now faces the issue of ambigous mapping method.

What is the correct solution to tackle this problem?

I have tried the following which solve the problems but are really **not ideal**:

- use an `expression(java(myObjectRepository.getById(myDto.getId()))` but this is not type safe at all and alot of hassle to implement.
- Override the `MyObject getById(Id id)` in the repository and use `@Named` and specify the name in the mapstruct `@Mapping` method in the `qualifiedByName`.

Is there a way to exclude `@Deprecated` methods from beeing used in the generation process? (See [here](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1151) for another reference)

Or any other suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Thank you!